# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I am facing this error don't know why this error is coming. I am using codeigniter and this is jquery error.

This is my **view page**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Attendance Type', 'Count'],
    ['Present', <?php echo $student_attendance_count['present']; ?>],
    ['Absent', <?php echo $student_attendance_count['absent']; ?>],
    ['On Leave', <?php echo $student_attendance_count['leave']; ?>],
    ['Attendance Not Maked', <?php echo $attendance_not_marked; ?>]
]);

var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities'
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
</script>
```

This is my HTML page check this for reference. If you need further details I will add here. I don't how this error is coming.

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3><span class="accordion_header">Student Strength</span></h3>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top">
                <table class="list">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 200px;"><b>Total student</b></td>
                        <td style="width: 50px;" class="text-right"><?php echo $total_student_count; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="attendance_color_present"><b>Present</b></td>
                        <td class="text-right attendance_color_present"><?php echo $student_attendance_count['present']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="attendance_color_absent"><b>Absent</b></td>
                        <td class="text-right attendance_color_absent"><?php echo $student_attendance_count['absent']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="attendance_color_leave"><b>Leave</b></td>
                        <td class="text-right attendance_color_leave"><?php echo $student_attendance_count['leave']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Attendance Not Marked</b></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><?php echo $attendance_not_marked =  $total_student_count - ($student_attendance_count['present'] + $student_attendance_count['absent'] + $student_attendance_count['leave']); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

<h3><span class="accordion_header">Attendance Details</span></h3>
<div>
    <div class="data_listing" style="margin-left: auto">
        <table class="list"  align="center" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 70%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center">Sr. No.</th>
                    <th style="width: 60%">Class Name</th>
                    <th style="width: 30%; text-align: center">Attendance Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
            $i = 1;
            $attendance_marked = 0;
            foreach ($class_section_attendance as $class) {
                if ($class['attendance_marked'] == 1) {
                    $image = '<img src ="' . base_url() . 'resources/images/icons/tick_circle.png" title="Attendance Marked" alt="Attendance Marked"/>';
                    $attendance_marked++;
                } else {
                    $image = '<img src ="' . base_url() . 'resources/images/icons/cross.png" title="Attendance Not Marked" alt="Attendance Not Marked"/>';
                }
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td style="text-align:center">' . $i++ . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $class['name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td style="text-align:center">' . $image . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            $not_marked = count($class_section_attendance) - $attendance_marked;
            echo '<tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Total Classes : <b>' . count($class_section_attendance) . '</b> | Attendaced Marked : <b>' . $attendance_marked . '</b> | Not Marked : <b>' . $not_marked . '</b> </td></tr>';
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Show the lines that load the Google Charts library, please.

Comment: You can put your code in document ready block, did you try it?

Comment: juhana It is already included in the header files->controller

Comment: @VaibhavDass cannot see.

Comment: Antti haapala@ What you are not able to see. all the jquery lib is included in the header file and I am calling that header files in Controller of codeigniter

Comment: @VaibhavDass Show your header files->controller. There's a good chance you haven't loaded Google Charts correctly, which is causing the problem, but it's impossible to say for sure without seeing how you do it. You need to load the visualization library separately, are you doing that?

Comment: Ok I am trying to include lib file separate in the view. @Juhana

Comment: Will you provide me the lib url to include here. @Juhana

Comment: @Juhana "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" this is coming now

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you are loading the Google Visualization API correctly.

Docs here:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs

You probably need something like this:

```
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API library and the piechart library.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     // ... draw the chart...
</script>
```

Comment: Note to Googlers, link is dead.  Revised link https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start