# Google Charts never render on slow network connections

Tags: javascript, charts, callback, google-visualization

We use Google Charts in our application to render donut charts.  One user has reported Javascript errors showing instead of the chart, and I've been trying to simulate this.  The closest I can get is to throttle the network speed in the browser to a very slow connection (e.g. GPRS in Firefox, or 20kbps in Chrome).  The causes some unusual things to happen that I did not expect.

Using the [example Google donut chart code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut) (verbatim - to prove that call backs are set) with a throttled connection ([Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/r6nkb2jv/) for convenience):

### Firefox

Firefox never renders the charts.  The callback method never gets invoked.  It's as if the browser "forgets" the callback, or the callback has a timeout property:

[image]

### Chrome

Chrome does not render the chart, and **intermittently** displays errors relating to `arrayToDataTable`.  I searched extensively for these errors, and all solutions appear to related to the [callback not being used correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905637/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-arraytodatatable-of-undefined) (e.g. rendering without waiting for the script to load).  Its like Chrome either gives up waiting and executes the callback anyway, or just aborts the logic flow.

[image]

### Points for clarity

1. Can anyone advise if `setOnLoadCallback` can timeout or abort, or callbacks in general?
2. Is there any workaround for this behaviour on slow connections?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try using the promise the load statement returns, rather than the callback.

for example, here is a typical statement, using the callback...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

instead, try using the promise...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(drawChart);    // <-- load statement returns a promise
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Sadly I'm afraid the outcome is the same as with my OP (nothing rendered).  This is shaping up to be well above my level of JS experience...

Comment: I figured as much, not sure what else you could try.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I sent a feedback message to Google on their respective docs page, but I don't think they maintain the project any more.  Will probably investigate a commercial alternative.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: there is one guy that maintains it, can't remember exact name but he is on here -- daniel liberte or something like that -- he usually comments on q's I can't answer

Comment: Thanks.  In the meantime I also found this GitHub issues page (https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues) which seems to be managed by someone else.  Perhaps Daniel does have some help...?!?